# Unix time to Date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have column `visit_time` and fields in this column are integers (unix time).

I am trying to make something like this: `SELECT * FROM visits WHERE DATE(visit_time) = CURDATE()`, but it isn't working...

How to make this code work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM visits WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(visit_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the other solutions presented here, you could determine the current unix time in MySQL. This might be faster for large data sets:

```
SELECT * FROM visits WHERE visit_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Comment: Indeed that's a better query - uses indexes if exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM `visits` WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`visit_time`)) = CURDATE()
```

See [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime), [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM visits WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(visit_time)) = CURDATE()
```

[MySQL Manual :: Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: This means converting every instance of visits.visit_time in order to compare with a single, static value - OTOH if you used WHERE visit_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) there's only 2 conversions, and the optimizer would be able to use an index on visit_time to find the rows.

Comment: If you prefer a different answer then write it (in a new answer) and collect the upvotes! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) for this:

```
SELECT * FROM visits WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(visit_time)) = CURDATE()
```